# How to examine both certificates of a twice code-signed executable?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, code-signing, x509certificate2

I have an executable signed with 2 different certificates. I need to examine both of these certificates.

I can examine one of them by creating an X509Certificate via its CreateFromSignedFile() method.

```
X509Certificate myCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(myExecutable);
```

The problem is that I can only examine a single certificate this way. I need to get them both.

How can I instantiate both certificates used to sign this assembly?

Comment: Will be PowerShell code acceptable?